# Unknown Provider in AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-factory

I am getting the infamous unknown provider error, and looked into every potential answer up here but I think that I am missing something:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'myAppControllers',
    'myAppServices',
    'myAppFilters'
]).config([
    '$locationProvider',
    function(
        $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false,
            rewriteLinks: false
        });
    }]);

var myAppControllers = angular.module('myAppControllers', []);

var myAppServices = angular.module('myAppServices', []);

var myAppFilters = angular.module('myAppFilters', []);
```

**Item.js**

```
myAppServices.factory('Item',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/items/:id');
    });
```

**ItemService.js (1)**

```
myAppServices.factory('itemService',
    function($q,
             $http,
             Item) {

        return {
            delete: function(id){

// Item, $q and $http are undefined here

                return Item.delete({id: id}).$promise;
            }
        };
    });
```

alternative **ItemService.js (2)**

```
myAppServices.factory('itemService', [
    '$q',
    '$http',
    'Item', // If I don't inject it here I can use this service with $q and $http
    function($q,
             $http,
             Item) {
        return {
            delete: function(id){
                return Item.delete(id).$promise;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And in my controller:

```
myAppControllers.controller('ItemsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'itemService',
    function(
        $scope,
        itemService) {

        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.ItemService = ItemService;

        ctrl.deleteItem = function(id){

            ctrl.itemService.delete(id)
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });

        };
    }]);
```

1. So if I try like in **(1)**, I am getting undefined.delete is not a function in `itemService`.
2. If I try as in **(2)**,  the app fails to load with:

   `Unknown provider: ItemProvider <- Item <- itemService`

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.

- You need to have `myAppServices` as a dependency of `myAppControllers` in order to use it in a controller.

  So, following should be how you do it:

  ```
  var myAppServices = angular.module('myAppServices', []);
  var myAppControllers = angular.module('myAppControllers', ['myAppServices']);
  ```
- In `myAppServices` module you have `Item` service which uses `$resource` but you haven't injected `ngResource` as a dependency of `myAppServices`.

Here's your [**code in plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dzRnxS8wrUV2oFMXJwXc?p=preview) without errors

**EDIT**: Also make sure all your files are included in `index.html` properly!

Comment: Actually, without the `Item` resource, I can use any service defined in `myAppServices` module in `myAppControllers`, as I am injecting all other modules for `myApp`. I have just tried it. It failed with the exact same error(s).

Comment: I am still playing with it, still getting the unknown provider ItemProvider error.

Comment: I know, I have the exact same copy not working on my PC, which is driving me nuts right now. It is still looking for `ItemProvider`!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have :)

Comment: You won't believe but apparently, my Grunt minify/uglify task didn't include `Item.js`.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral oh shoot! that's weird! hope it works fine now!

Comment: If you could update your answer, I would be happy to accept it, since you really tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

i think in $resource ur are missing argument it should look like

```
$resource('/api/items/:id', {id:'@id'});
```

Try **(1)** again , undefined is because of this

and also ur delete should be look like this

```
return Item.delete({id : id}).$promise;
```

Comment: Sorry that's a typo when typing the question, it is not in the code.

Comment: @PankajParkar :P

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake on my behalf that is only on StackOverflow, not on the file I am using in my project.